# Creating multiple records with one form Rails and Simple_Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm trying to create a form with simple_form that allows me to create multiple records.  I'll share some code and explain some more below.
First I built as many employee objects as I required in your controller:

```
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @employees = Array.new(3) { @restaurant.aware_employees.build } 

  end
```

Then I created a route to handle creating multiple

```
  resources :aware_employees do
    post 'create_multiple', on: :collection
    resources :restaurant_roles
  end
```

Then I created the view

```
<%= simple_form_for create_multiple_user_restaurant_aware_employees_path(@user, @restaurant) do |q| %>

        <% @employees.each do |employee|%>

            <%= simple_fields_for employee do |f| %>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-row">
                        <p class='form-label'>Name</p>
                        <%= f.input :name, label: false, input_html: { class: "req" }   %>
                        <span class='feedback'></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-row">
                        <p class='form-label'>Verifcation</p>
                        <%= f.input :verification, label: false, input_html: { class: "req" }  %>
                        <span class='feedback'></span>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-row">
                        <p class='form-label'>Hours</p>
                        <%= f.input :expiration, label: false, as: :date %>
                        <span class='feedback'></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 form-row">
                        <p class='form-label'>Role</p>
                        <%= f.association :restaurant_roles, label: false, multiple: true, collection: Role.all, label_method: :role, value: :id, input_html: { class: "chosen-select req", multiple: true, style: 'width:255px; height:200px;'}  %>
                        <span class='feedback'></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <%end%>
        <%= q.button :submit, value:'',:class => "nav-link"%>
    <%end%>
```

I'm not sure what's happening here. The error I am getting is that simple_form is routing the post request to the new action instead of create_multiple.  I don't know if i'm way off, but I feel like im falling down a rabbit hole here.

Here's the error message: 
No route matches [POST] "/users/1/restaurants/46/aware_employees/new"

Why does it think im posting to aware_employees#new?

Comment: I thought the first param for simple_form_for was the object it's operating on.
simple_form_for @employees, url: create_multiple_user_restaurant_aware_employees_path(@user, @restaurant)